# Version compatibility error with libCRFSuite.dylib (MacPorts)

Tags: macos, macports

I've been using the same Mac OS machine for a while and have upgraded several times, most recently to 10.12.4. Sometime in the past several months I started having errors like the following:

```
Foundation requires version 1.0.0 or later, but libCRFSuite.dylib provides version 0.0.0
```

This happens when I use particular applications, such as mercurial. Here is an example of the full error below:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/local/bin/hg", line 43, in <module>
    mercurial.util.setbinary(fp)
  File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/mercurial/demandimport.py", line 152, in __getattribute__
    self._load()
  File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/mercurial/demandimport.py", line 100, in _load
    mod = _hgextimport(_import, head, globals, locals, None, level)
  File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/mercurial/demandimport.py", line 53, in _hgextimport
    return importfunc(name, globals, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/mercurial/util.py", line 120, in <module>
    statfiles = getattr(osutil, 'statfiles', platform.statfiles)
  File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/mercurial/demandimport.py", line 152, in __getattribute__
    self._load()
  File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/mercurial/demandimport.py", line 100, in _load
    mod = _hgextimport(_import, head, globals, locals, None, level)
  File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/mercurial/demandimport.py", line 53, in _hgextimport
    return importfunc(name, globals, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/mercurial/__init__.py", line 120, in load_module
    mod = imp.load_module(name, *modinfo)
ImportError: dlopen(/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/mercurial/osutil.so, 2): Library not loaded: /usr/lib/libCRFSuite.dylib
  Referenced from: /System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Versions/C/Foundation
  Reason: Incompatible library version: Foundation requires version 1.0.0 or later, but libCRFSuite.dylib provides version 0.0.0
```

It looks like `libCRFSuite.dylib` is a somewhat esoteric OS library, and I suspect that some version compatibility issue occurred when I upgraded my OS but I'm not sure. Does anyone have any idea how I could fix this?

Comment: Do you happen to have any `DYLD_*` environment variables set? Note that `/usr/bin/env` and `/usr/bin/printenv` no longer display them due to Apple's system integrity protection, so you may have to do `(set | grep DYLD)` in your shell to see them.

Comment: Yes, that was it! I cleared my `DYLD_*` variables designated in `.bashrc` and everything started working. Thanks so much.

Comment: Yeah, you really shouldn't be setting any of those. Especially `DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH` is very different from Linux' `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` and often leads to such issues.